# Design | maintainable | conditionals view | MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Have a view where I need to show address details in view

```
Name
Street
State , City, Washington
```

Now the sequence of this address needs to be differ for each country like for China they want below format

```
Name
State , City, Washington
Street
```

So what have done is written if else statement in view and have the format , earlier have no issues as this was only for one or 2 countries

But now am seeing same kind of different request for each countries, this will make my view very heavy and not maintainable

Can someone provide good pattern to have it more maintainable like one is have different partial view for each country and load that partial view etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the best option is to have different views for different countries and return them from controller based on some identifier.This will keep the code maintainable.For sure dont use if - else.
You can create multiple partial views for each country if not all your fields are dynamically sequenced.Keep the static ones on the main view and dynamic in partial view.

Now If you have far too many countries and don't want to maintain individual views then another option would be to Create a HtmlHelper extension and use that to create the view dynamically in the code and return MvcHtmlString which can be used in the view as shown below.

```
 @Html.CountryFields('us')
```

EDIT:

Also check below link it may be useful in your scenario (good example of using multiple views mentioned above)

http://brianreiter.org/2011/03/23/simple-asp-net-mvc-globalization-with-graceful-fallback/

Answer (score 0):

here is just an idea, maybe it can help you, hope so

you might need to add new `tables Address(Id,Format)` that will store the different available formats and the table `AddressFormat(AddressId,CountryId)` as join table with `Country` table

for example:

```
Name
Street
State , City, Washington
```

can be formatted as `"{0}<br/>{1}<br/>{2},{3},{4}",Name,Street,State,City,...`

and for china as `"{0}<br/>{2},{3},{4}<br/>{1}",Name,Street,State,City`

so in the table Address you will have these data

```
Id            Format
1             {0}<br/>{1}<br/>{2},{3},{4}
2             {0}<br/>{2},{3},{4}<br/>{1}
```

and in your view you can use

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(Model.Format,Model.Name,Model.Street,Model.State,Model.City,Model.WashingtonField))
```

so the idea here the parameter indexes are the same but want to reorder them while displaying them

hope this idea to give you a hint

Comment: Thanks Hadi but if we use HTML.Raw then there will be security issue as the content will not ne encode right ?

Comment: you don't have problem because you are displaying data controlled by you, the end user will not add the details and if you want to allow them to add the html then you can use the Html.Encode when you want to display the properties.

Comment: Thanks all for valuable inputs

Comment: @Rajesh if my answer solved your problem, kindly mark it as answer, and if you still have any doubt or questions, ask them